# Using RDFDataMgr to write model, but after packaging with maven-assembly:assembly, it throws NullPointerException

Tags: jena

This is how I write my `jena.model.Model`, using `RDFDataMgr`:

```
        try {
            Lang schema = Lang.RDFXML;
            // System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            File file = new File(owlDir);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
            outputStream.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n".getBytes());

            RDFDataMgr.write(outputStream, model, schema);

            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Before packaging, this code worked fine.
But after packaging using maven-assembly:assembly(insied IDEA), and then import this code in another project, the model writing process throws NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFWriterBuilder.build(RDFWriterBuilder.java:137)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFWriterBuilder.output(RDFWriterBuilder.java:149)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.write$(RDFDataMgr.java:1260)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.write(RDFDataMgr.java:1053)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.write(RDFDataMgr.java:1044)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.write(RDFDataMgr.java:985)
    at seu.edu.kse.tools.ModelSaver.save2owl(ModelSaver.java:126)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

ModelSaver.java:126:

```
    RDFDataMgr.write(outputStream, model, schema);
```

`ARQ.globalContext` in package `org.apache.jena.query` is null.
Is there something wrong with the packaging using `assembly`?

I tried using `model.write(outputStream, "RDF/XML")` to write the model. This throws no exceptions after packaging, but the content of the result file is very much different from the result file wrote before packaging with all the `<owl ...>` tags missing.

Answer (score 1):

See this page on [Combining Apache Jena jars](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/jena-repack.html). Basically, Jena jar files define initialisation steps in a file that is located at path `META-INF/services/org.apache.jena.sys.JenaSubsystemLifecycle` in the jar. After repackaging with the Assembly plugin, this initialisation file is not present, and hence Jena initialisation is incomplete. This can be solved by manually creating the appropriate file, or automatically with the Maven Shade Plugin.